# WP_Site_Query vs. WP_Network_Query in WordPress 4.6

Tags: multisite, query, core

Can someone explain the difference between [`WP_Site_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_site_query/) and [`WP_Network_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_network_query/) in [WordPress 4.6](https://wordpress.org/news/2016/08/pepper/)?

- **`WP_Network_Query()`** : Core class used for querying networks.
- **`WP_Site_Query()`** : Core class used for querying sites.
- **`WP_Term_Query()`** : Class used for querying terms.

Are there examples when you would query the [Network](https://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Network) vs. the [Site](https://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Site) vs. [Posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Post)?

Wouldn't a [`WP_Site_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_site_query/) just be a [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)? I've been hoping for a way to query posts across multiple sites but I don't think this is that.

I wonder if [Multisite Focused Changes in 4.6](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/07/08/multisite-focused-changes-in-4-6/) would help...

Answer (score 1):

When you set WordPress to multisite, in an "out of box" fashion, you create a single network of sites. Let's, say, a network of food blogs.

With plugins like [WP Multi Network](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/) you can set up multiple networks. You could split that food blogs network into several networks: mediterranean food blogs, brazilian food blogs, thai food blogs, wine blogs, etc

From what i grasp reading https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/07/08/multisite-focused-changes-in-4-6/ and both classes sources (and their related functions/other classes), WP_Site_Query queries about existing sites in a single network (e.g. find all active sites in that network) and WP_Network_Query do the same across several networks (e.g. find all archive blogs on all those networks).

Comment: That makes sense. So where is the information on setting up multiple networks? I really want to see examples of queries you would run against each too. I know... I'm impatient with fresh releases.

Comment: I guess for Multi Network you would need a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/